# When/how does Apache kill a child process that you spawn in PHP?

Tags: apache-2.2, mpm-prefork

Not sure if this is more appropriate for Server Fault or Stack Overflow, but here goes.

I'm using mod_php on Apache MPM prefork and spawning a new process like-so:

```
<?php
exec("/usr/bin/php -f backgroundScript.php &");
?>
```

Assuming that the new backgroundScript.php child process runs for a long time…

1) Is the parent PHP process now considered idle? Does it return to the server pool?

2) If Apache does kill the parent PHP process to return to `MinSpareServers`, will backgroundScript.php also get cleaned-up or continue running indefinitely?

3) Are there other ways that Apache may inadvertently kill the backgroundScript.php child process? `service httpd stop` perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to run application in background and forget?

[there are many posts regarding this on php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)

Also, note from the exec man:

> Note:
>
> If a program is started with this function, in order for it to
>   continue running in the background, the output of the program must be
>   redirected to a file or another output stream. Failing to do so will
>   cause PHP to hang until the execution of the program ends.

same [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12842767/php-background-process-using-exec-function) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14555971/php-exec-background-process-issues) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8961470/how-to-make-shell-exec-run-in-background-while-php-continues)  etc

I've got ugly code, violating these rules:

> ```
> <?php
> echo "pre";
> exec("someuglylongandworkingthingwithoutput &");
> echo "post";
> ?>
> ```

Just tested on my fedora box with default apache+php (prefork + module), i've killed processes with killall -9 /usr/sbin/httpd

1. despite `&` - no, didn't, it's still considered as running. my background app is still running
2. according to my test above - it will continue
3. depends how init script terminates apache, same according to p 1.

After adding `/dev/null` - everything's fine, parent process id is "1".